# Spark reduceByKey and how to minimise Shuffling

Tags: apache-spark

I'm processing a table like this:

```
ID    f1
001   1
001   2
001   3
002   0
002   7
```

and I want to calculate the sum of f1 column of the same ID, and create a new column with sum, that is:

```
ID    f1   sum_f1
001   1    6
001   2    6
001   3    6
002   0    7
002   7    7
```

My solution is calculate the sum with `reduceByKey` and then join the result with the original table:

```
val table = sc.parallelize(Seq(("001",1),("001",2),("001",3),("002",0),("002",7)))
val sum = table.reduceByKey(_ + _)
val result = table.leftOuterJoin(sum).map{ case (a,(b,c)) => (a, b, c.getOrElse(-1) )}
```

and I get right result:

```
result.collect.foreach(println)
```

output:

```
(002,0,7)
(002,7,7)
(001,1,6)
(001,2,6)
(001,3,6)
```

The problem is there are 2 shuffle stages in the code, one in reduceByKey, the other in leftOuterJoin, but if I write the code in Hadoop MapReduce, It's easy to get the same result with only 1 shuffle stage(with more than once use of `outputer.collect` function in reduce stage).
So I was wondering if there is a better way to do the work with one shuffle. Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: I think the question's title should be modified, in order to represent explicitly your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another approach is to use `aggregateByKey`. This may be diffcult to understand method
but from spark docs:

> (`groupByKey`) Note: This operation may be very expensive. If you are grouping in order
>   to perform an aggregation (such as a sum or average) over each key,
>   using `PairRDDFunctions.aggregateByKey` or `PairRDDFunctions.reduceByKey`
>   will provide much better performance.

Also `aggregateByKey` is a generic function so it's worth knowing.

Of course we are not doing "simple aggregation such as sum" here so the
performance benefits of this approach vs `groupByKey` may not be present.
Obviously benchmarking both approaches on real data would be a good idea.

Here is detailed implementation:

```scala
// The input as given by OP here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36455419/spark-reducebykey-and-keep-other-columns
val table = sc.parallelize(Seq(("001", 1), ("001", 2), ("001", 3), ("002", 0), ("002", 7)))

// zero is initial value into which we will aggregate things.
// The second element is the sum.
// The first element is the list of values which contributed to this sum.
val zero = (List.empty[Int], 0)

// sequencer will receive an accumulator and the value.
// The accumulator will be reset for each key to 'zero'.
// In this sequencer we add value to the sum and append to the list because
// we want to keep both.
// This can be thought of as "map" stage in classic map/reduce.
def sequencer(acc: (List[Int], Int), value: Int) = {
  val (values, sum) = acc
  (value :: values, sum + value)
}

// combiner combines two lists and sums into one.
// The reason for this is the sequencer may run in different partitions
// and thus produce partial results. This step combines those partials into
// one final result.
// This step can be thought of as "reduce" stage in classic map/reduce.
def combiner(left: (List[Int], Int), right: (List[Int], Int)) = {
  (left._1 ++ right._1, left._2 + right._2)
}

// wiring it all together.
// Note the type of result it produces:
// Each key will have a list of values which contributed to the sum, sum the sum itself.
val result: RDD[(String, (List[Int], Int))] = table.aggregateByKey(zero)(sequencer, combiner)

// To turn this to a flat list and print, use flatMap to produce:
// (key, value, sum)
val flatResult: RDD[(String, Int, Int)] = result.flatMap(result => {
  val (key, (values, sum)) = result
  for (value <- values) yield (key, value, sum)
})

// collect and print
flatResult.collect().foreach(println)
```

This produces:

```
(001,1,6)
(001,2,6)
(001,3,6)
(002,0,7)
(002,7,7)
```

Here is also a gist with a fully runnable version of the above
if you want to reference it: https://gist.github.com/ppanyukov/253d251a16fbb660f225fb425d32206a

Answer (score 0):

You could use `groupByKey` to get the list of values, take the sum and recreate the lines with `flatMapValues`:

```
val g = table.groupByKey().flatMapValues { f1s =>
  val sum = f1s.reduce(_ + _)
  f1s.map(_ -> sum)
}
```

But `reduce` in this code works locally, so this will fail if a single key has too many values.

Another approach is to keep the `join`, but partition first, so the join is cheap:

```
val partitioned = table.partitionBy(
  new org.apache.spark.HashPartitioner(table.partitions.size))
partitioned.cache // May or may not improve performance.
val sum = partitioned.reduceByKey(_ + _)
val result = partitioned.join(sum)
```

I cannot guess which would be faster. I'd benchmark all of the options.

Comment: Thank you! I'll benchmark them when I'm free and tell you in the comment.